# How to avoid the "self signed certificate" error when testing requests in SwaggerHub?

Tags: certificate, self-signed-certificate, swaggerhub

I have been recently using SwaggerHub and I keep getting a "self-signed certificate" error, the error code is 500 - internal server error. I'm hosting our API on AWS, and I have inputted the correct host and the endpoints work when I use them straight in my browser, but SwaggerHub "try it out" keeps returning me these errors.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right down the bottom of the page in SwaggerHub, there is this cool little button!

[image: button]